# How can I stop my browser from opening up itself and loading a page when internet is connected?

Tags: networking, google-chrome, browser, batch-file, url

When I connect to the internet through a dongle (ISP: Tata Photon+/Tata Indicom) it opens up my default browser (google chrome) and logs on to the homepage of my ISP which is integrated by Yahoo!. I really don't like this feature as I don't need to surf through the browser always when I connect to the internet. I need to deal with torrents, software updates etc. The browser is quite slow when it opens this page and my computer lags because I usually deal with programming softwares which consume high RAM(2 GB) and the browser opens up and adds fuel to my burning RAM. So I want to disable this feature. I tried to locate files like URL files, batch files etc. in the dongle driver's installation directory which could be causing it, but couldn't find any. I also contacted my ISP if they could instruct me how to disable it, but they tell please contact him/her and those hims/hers don't respond to my call. Now all that is left is to disable this feature by myself. How can I do it?

Comment: If you don't go through this process then your internet wouldn't work until you did.

Answer (score 0):

this really is a stupid hack and in my opinion not worth the effort but if it uses your default browser and calls it with a command line argument you could set up a batch file as your default for the "http://" protocol association or whatever it seems to use. You should be able to find out by viewing the Command Line column in the process tab of the task manager.

That batch file should check if the given argument is the url your isp forces you to open and start your browser if it's not.

Even if you get this to work it won't work flawlessly. Your browser won't be able to check if it's the default browser. You might have problems with the execution path.

However if you still want to do this you have to start finding out what causes your browser to open that url.